# unexpected infinite loop in c++

Tags: c++, while-loop, passwords, infinite

I'm working in a project and the task is to make the signup function
so when I try several test cases in password function I got stuck in an infinite loop when I try to type an invalid password without giving me a chance to retype the password.
Thanks in advance...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
#define size 40
int main(){
    bool flag = true;
    while (flag){
        bool flagS = false, flagN = false; int count = 0;
        char password[size] = { 0 };
        cout << "Type your Password .....\n Note :: Must be more than 8 characters including at least one number and one special character...\n";
        cin.get(password, size);
        count = strlen(password);
        for (int z = 0; z < count; z++){
            if (password[z] >= 48 && password[z] <= 57)
                flagN = 1;
            if ((password[z] >= 33 && password[z] <= 47) || (password[z] >= 58 && password[z] <= 64))
                flagS = 1;
        }

        if ((flagS == 1) && (flagN == 1) && (count >= 8))
        {
            cout << "Valide Password ...\nCongrats!! ..you created a NEW account.." << endl;
            flag = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "invalide password..\nPlease try again..\n";
            flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *error: 'strlen' was not declared in this scope. note: 'strlen' is defined in header '<cstring>'; did you forget to '#include <cstring>'?*

Comment: Yeah, this question is not very well formated. What have you tried changing? You basically asked the question and left.

Comment: Also your array is never wiped. When you do cin.get your array still have the password from last time.

Comment: Your boolean variables should be better named: flag, flagN, flagS. It is clear that a boolean variable is a flag, the question is, what it flags. The name should be about that.

Comment: Another thing i would recommend you using C++ functions, you are basically coding c++ with C syntax. There is so much easier way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Boolean variables should also be used with true and false, especially when comparing, you can compare directly: if(flag), if(!flag) or at least if (flag == true). You could step through the program with a debugger and/or print intermediate results to know, where it goes wrong

Comment: @AllamoOlsson  the error was that not wiping the array thank you very much for helping me

Comment: Yes I know, the error was on the cin stream, but I would say that a good practice is to whpe the array since you will loop thru the thing anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must write `cin` inside of `while` loop. And this will fix your problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
#define size 40
int main(){
    bool flag = true;
    bool flagS = false, flagN = false; int count = 0;
    char password[size] = { 0 };

    cout << "Type your Password .....\n Note :: Must be more than 8 characters including at least one number and one special character...\n";

    while (cin >> password && flag){

        count = strlen(password);
        for (int z = 0; z < count; z++){
            if (password[z] >= 48 && password[z] <= 57)
                flagN = true;
            if ((password[z] >= 33 && password[z] <= 47) || (password[z] >= 58 && password[z] <= 64))
                flagS = true;
        }

        if ((flagS) && (flagN) && (count >= 8))
        {
            cout << "Valide Password ...\nCongrats!! ..you created a NEW account.." << endl;
            flag = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "invalide password..\nPlease try again..\n" << "Type your Password .....\n Note :: Must be more than 8 characters including at least one number and one special character...\n";;
            flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`std::istream::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) does not remove the newline from the stream. This means the next call to `std::istream::get` immediately finds the newline and reads nothing into the buffer, sets the failbit, and returns. Because the steream is now in the fail state all subsequent reads instantly fail. You could `cin.ignore()` the newline, but a more direct approach is to use [`std::istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) because it removes the newline for you.

Always test the stream state after an IO transaction to make sure it succeeded.

Side note:

Prefer to use `std::string` and `std::getline` to raw character arrays and functions that use them. `std::istream::get` and `std::istream::getline` both mark the stream as failed if the buffer provided is too small. The `string` provided to  `std::getline` will be resized, so as long as you have dynamic storage remaining, buffer over runs and the errors raised to prevent them are a non-problem. If the system cannot allocate a buffer of sufficient size for the `string` an exception is thrown to make you aware of the problem.

Prefer to use letters, for example `'A'` to a raw ASCII code. For one thing the intent of `'A"` is immediately recognizable to even the most raw of programmers and there is always the possibility that the implementation does not use ASCII as the default encoding.